# Assigning a variable to a long column expression for use in ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to assign a variable to a long expression?

This is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_type.type AS "Customer type",
        count(customer_bio) over(w) as "Number of type",
        cast(cast(count(customer_bio) over(w) AS DECIMAL (7,2)) / cast(count(customer_bio) over() AS DECIMAL (7,2)) * 100 AS DECIMAL (7,2)) as "Percentage",
        sum(count(customer_bio)) OVER (ORDER by type) AS "Cumm. Sum"
        FROM customer_type
        JOIN customer_bio
        ON customer_type.type_id=customer_bio.type_id
        GROUP BY type, customer_bio
WINDOW w as (PARTITION by type) 
ORDER BY sum(count(customer_bio)) OVER (ORDER by type) DESC
```

The code works, but the last line: `ORDER BY sum(count(customer_bio)) OVER (ORDER by type) DESC`:
Is there a way I can assign lets say the variable 'tp' to this `sum(count(customer_bio)) OVER (ORDER by type)` so that the code will be a lot shorter to something like `ORDER BY tp OVER (ORDER by type) DESC`?

I use Postgresql

Comment: `ORDER BY "Cumm. Sum" DESC`

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is useless as you are also grouping the result.